# Chart.js - 2 does not display Axes labels

Tags: javascript, chart.js, vue-chartjs

i am trying to plot a line graph using vue-chartjs and Chart.js (2.7.1).
the graph is displayed, but there are no xAxes and yAxes labels.

This is my options object:

```
title: {
    display: true,
    text: 'Title',
},
responsive: true,
maintainAspectRatio: false,
elements: {
    line: {
        fill: false
    }        
},
scales: {
    xAxes: {
        scaleLabel: {
            display: true,
            labelString: 'LabelX',
        }
    },
    yAxes: {
        scaleLabel: {
            display: true,
            labelString: 'LabelY',
        }
    },
}
```

I think that **scales.xAxes.scaleLabel** don't working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to use V3 syntax with V2 that won't work. You will have to put it like this:

```
scales:{
  xAxes: [
    {
       scaleLabel: {
         display: true,
          labelString: 'text'
       }
     }
  ],
  yAxes: [
    {
       scaleLabel: {
         display: true,
          labelString: 'text'
       }
     }
  ]
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

In [Chartjs 2.x.x](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/2.7.3/axes/labelling.html) version, you have to specify scales options in an array not an object.

Try like this

```
 xAxes: [{
  scaleLabel: {
        display: true,
        labelString: 'LabelX',
  },
  gridLines: {
    display: true
  }
}]
```